# Code coverage failure inside Flux map method

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

Sample code

```
Flux<Object> result=userMessagesDataStore.getByParamFilter(params)  ;
    result.map(r -> {
        UserMessageV1 v1 = (UserMessageV1) r;
        v1.setClientName("");
        return v1;
    });
```

For the above code unit test is working fine but when i check in sonar getting code coverage issue(Check the image for reference).
[image: Sonar cube analysis]

Can anyone help me to resove this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda expression inside is not called. Use its return type and assign it back to the `result` variable, otherwise the transformed `Flux` is unused and the original one remains unchanged.

```
Flux<Object> result = userMessagesDataStore.getByParamFilter(params);
result = result.map(r -> {
    UserMessageV1 v1 = (UserMessageV1) r;
    v1.setClientName("");
    return v1;
});
```

Notice the [`Flux#map(Function)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) JavaDoc, particularly it's return type:

> **Returns:** a transformed Flux

Comment: How do you cover lines of code on doOnComplete on return statement??